# Copying file from one directory to another by matching font cases of the file name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to copy files from one directory to another by file name. My code is doing that, but if I have 2 files, of different types, of the same name, but of different font cases, it is copying both of them.
How do I copy by matching font cases? I do not want to use regular expressions.

Example:

DIR1:

file1= test.txt

file2= Test.html

My code is copying both the files. But, I want to copy only file1.

Can someone please help me figure out, where I am going wrong?

Following is my code:

```
def copy_file():
    import os
    import sys
    import shutil
    import glob
    src=input('Enter the source path: ')
    dst=input('Enter the destination path: ')
    file_name=input('Enter the file name to copy: ')
    count=0
    if os.path.exists(src):
        os.chdir(src)
    else:
        print('Enter a valid path')
        sys.exit(1)
    file_list=glob.glob(file_name+'*')
    if os.path.exists(dst):
        for f in file_list:
            shutil.copy(f,dst)
            count+=1
        print('%d files copied' %count)
    else:
        print('Invalid destination')
```

Comment: What operating system do you use? This is probably only possible if you use Linux. Globbing does apparently not work, do `os.scandir` or `os.listdir` and filter manually.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are taking a file name without its extension, then globing the file name to any extension, the problem comes with your OS's file system that most provably is case insensitive (like Windows NTFS or MacOS HFS+), for those file systems `FileName` is the same as `filename` thus globing will bring both, to solve your problem you will need to compare file names within python after the globing which will do the comparison case sensitive.

```
def copy_file():
    import os
    import sys
    import shutil
    import glob
    src=input('Enter the source path: ')
    dst=input('Enter the destination path: ')
    file_name=input('Enter the file name to copy: ')
    count=0
    if os.path.exists(src):
        os.chdir(src)
    else:
        print('Enter a valid path')
        sys.exit(1)
    file_list= [fname for fname in glob.glob(file_name+'*') if fname.startswith(file_name)]
    if os.path.exists(dst):
        for f in file_list:
            shutil.copy(f,dst)
            count+=1
        print('%d files copied' %count)
    else:
        print('Invalid destination')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. try it and let me know.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import re
import sys
import shutil

def copy_file():

    src=input('Enter the source path: ')
    dst=input('Enter the destination path: ')
    file_name=input('Enter the file name to copy: ')
    count=0
    if os.path.exists(src):
        os.chdir(src)
    else:
        print('Enter a valid path')
        sys.exit(1)
    file_list= findfiles(file_name, src)
    if os.path.exists(dst):
        for f in file_list:
            shutil.copy(f,dst)
            count+=1
        print('%d files copied' %count)
    else:
        print('Invalid destination')

def findfiles(which, where='.'):
    '''Returns list of filenames from `where` path matched by 'which'
       shell pattern.'''    

    rule = re.compile(fnmatch.translate(which))
    return [name for name in os.listdir(where) if rule.match(name)]
```